# Python celery - tuples in arguments converted to lists

Tags: python, redis, celery

I noticed this when using the `delay()` function to asynchronously send tasks. If I queue a task such as `task.delay(("tuple",))`, celery will store the argument as `["tuple"]` and later the function will get the list back and not the tuple. Guessing this is because the data is being stored into json.

This is fine for tuples, however I'm using namedtuples which can no longer be referenced properly once converted to a list. I see the obvious solution of switching the namedtuples out with dicts. Is there any other method? I couldn't seem to find anything in the configuration for celery.

I'm using redis as the broker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to preserve the python native data structure I'd recommend using one of the serialization modules such a cPickle which will preserve the data structure but won't be readable outside of Python.

Answer (score 0):

Celery uses [Kombo](https://github.com/celery/kombu) for message serialization. Currently the default serializer is 'json' which doesn't help much when we want to deserialize NamedTuple.
You can override the default serializer with your own one or just use 'simplejson' which, by default uses the option *namedtuple_as_object*=True (see [simplejson](https://simplejson.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)).

The following solution worked for me:

```
from kombu import serialization

serialization.register('simplejson',simplejson.dumps, simplejson.loads, 'application/json', 'utf-8')

app = Celery(...) # define your app

app.conf.task_serializer = 'simplejson'
```

And that's it. From now on every task that imports app and uses the annotation

```
@app.task
def task(...)
```

will use simplejson serializer instead of json.